# Ember Rails 'POST' Nested Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, rails-api

When saving nested resources (ex saving a highlight that belongs to a property) it seems that Ember doesn't pickup on the nested route hierarchy and 'POSTS' to just 'api/v1/highlights' when i need it to 'POST' to 'api/v1/properties/property_id/highlights'. So I thought about un-nesting the routes on the back-end to solve it and passing the property_id somehow, but it would be a lot easier to just be able to have it understand the correct route. I came across the buildURL mixin to build the correct path for each time and was wondering if that's the best way to do it and is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for all the help in advance

Here are parts of my code...

routes.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
namespace :v1 do
  resources :users, only: [:show, :update] 
  resources :user_devices, only: [:show]
  resources :properties do

    resources :highlights do
      resources :options
    end
  end 
  resources :fields
end
```

end

router.js

```
this.route('properties', function() {
this.route('new');

this.route('property', {path: ':property_id'}, function() {
  this.route('edit');
  this.route('details');

  this.route('highlights', function() {
    this.route('new');

    this.route('highlight', {path: ':highlight_id'}, function() {
      this.route('edit');

      this.route('options', function() {
        this.route('new');

        this.route('option', {path: ':option_id'}, function() {
          this.route('edit');
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

adapter

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000',
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});
```

highlight model in highlight.js

```
property: DS.belongsTo('property', {async: true }),
```

property model in property.js

```
highlights: DS.hasMany('highlight', {async: true }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general convention when using ember-data is that each models endpoints are siblings of each other.

If you really wanted to do this you would have to build your own adapter, which is much more effort then doing things according to convention.

so your routes.rb would look like

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users, only: [:show, :update] 
    resources :user_devices, only: [:show]
    resources :properties
    resources :highlights
    resources :options
  end 
  resources :fields
end
```

models/highlights.js

```
export default Model.extend({
  property: DS.belongsTo('property', {async: true })
})
```

models/property.js

```
export default Model.extend({
  property: DS.hasMany('highlight', {async: true })
})
```

models/options.js

```
export default Model.extend({
  property: DS.belongsTo('highlight', {async: true })
})
```

action in property controller for example

```
save:function(){
   highlight.save().then(function(highlight){
     property.get(highlights).pushObject(highlight);
     property.save();
   });
}
```

when property.save executes, your adapter will automatically add `highlight_ids :[1]` to the payload it sends to the server

Comment: Really appreciate the help. Ideally I want to save it in the highlights/new controller so how would I go about getting access to the property that the highlight belongs to (pretty much have the same code you wrote in the controller)? Tried defining it in the route but still having issues with it. Thanks in advance